# Proving an ellipse is compact.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

For the set $$S=\left \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (x+1)^2+y^2\leq9 \right \}$$ Prove it is compact.

To prove it I'll see it is bounded and closed:

Bounded:
Taking $s=(x,y)\in S$, one has 
$\lVert s \rVert^2 = x^2 + y^2 \leq (x+1)^2 + y^2 \leq 9$.

Closed: The function $f\colon (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto (x+1)^2 + y^2$ is continuous, and $\{9\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $S = f^{-1}(\{9\})$ is closed.

I dont really understand any of these two proofs. For $s\in S$, how showing $||s||^2\leq C$ proves a set $S$ is bounded?

And for the second proof, why the preimage of a continous function evaluated in a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ proves the set built by $f(s)=\mathbb{R}$ is compact?

Comment: Well note that the singleton set $\{9\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $f$ is continuous inverse image of closed sets must map to a closed set and hence $f^{-1}(\{9\})=S$ is closed. But i think the proof is wrong. I think it should be $[0,9]$ instead of just the singleton set $\{9\}$.

Comment: Intuitively, $||s||^2 \le C$ means $s$ is contained in a closed ball of radius $C$ centered at $(0, 0)$, so $S$ is bounded.

Comment: $S$ is not equal to $f^{-1}(\{9\})$, but rather $f^{-1}((-\infty, 9])$. As $f$ is nonnegative, however, we can rewrite this as $f^{-1}([0, 9])$. Either way, the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map is closed.

Comment: @S.C., good point, but then I think it needs to be proven that the range of $f$ is indeed $[0,9]$.  That's probably not too hard but overall I wonder if it'd be easier to show that the complement of $S$ is open?  And is it allowed to just take for granted that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Wait, $S=f^{-1}((-\infty, 9])$ not $f^{-1}(\{9\})$ Anyway $(-\infty, 9]$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,y)=(x+1)^2+y^2$ is continous so by theorem $S$ is closed because is a preimage of a closed set of a continuous function.

Comment: You don't have to take it for granted that $f$ is continuous, but it's essentially trivial if you know that compositions and sums of continuous functions are continuous and that $x\mapsto x+1$ amd $x\mapsto x^2$ are continuous (which implies that $(x, y)\mapsto x+1$, $(x, y)\mapsto x^2$, and $(x, y)\mapsto y^2$ are continuous).

Comment: Very true. As @lxion points out $S=f^{-1}[-\infty,9]$ is correct. I honestly don't know how to see $f$ is continuous though? Would anyone care to explain?

Comment: I think that @Michael Lee gives a really good explaination. :). I'm too  slow. :D.

Comment: Sure it's trivial, but only if the machinery is available.  In my intro real analysis course I know I definitely wouldn't have been allowed to use continuity if the topic hadn't been discussed yet and I was just trying to prove a set in $\Bbb R^2$ is bounded and closed.  I suppose we can assume it's ok since continuity is in the proof OP provided and it sounds like OP didn't write it (otherwise OP would probably understand it).

Comment: Isn't continuity basically the first thing you talk about in intro real analysis? After you've finished constructing the reals, that is. :)

Comment: @tilper you're right, but in the OP, John keeper uses the theorem, so I don't see why we can't use it. ;)

Comment: @Ixion, I know, I said that.  But to be fair, I edited it probably after you started typing.  :P

Comment: @MichaelLee, we used Baby Rudin my class so we had [quite a bit before continuity](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/principles-of-mathematical-analysis).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I think I understand it better now. One more thing, which theorem proves that $S$ is closed if it is a preimage of a closed set of a continuous function? I understand it intuitively, but where can I find a formal demostration?

Comment: @JohnKeeper It's the definition of continuity, actually. A continuous function between two topological spaces is a function such that the preimage of every open set is open. Therefore, if $S$ is closed, then $S^c$ is open, so $f^{-1}(S^c)$ is open, and thus $(f^{-1}(S^c))^c = f^{-1}(S)$ is closed.

Comment: If you want a proof of equivalence of this definition of continuity with the definition usually used in the context of metric spaces (the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition), try [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~mjunge/metric2.pdf).